# Android Facebook, no chat

Tags: facebook, chat

I got my LG Optimus 2X and installed the facebook app however, there is no chat anywhere, not even in menu, is there a way to allow this?

Answer (score 6):

Facebook have a separate app these days called [Facebook Messenger](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.facebook.orca), this has both Facebook's chat and inbox features in it. Why they've split it out into a separate app now, I don't know, but this should give you what you're after:

> Facebook Messenger is a faster way to send mobile messages to friends.
>   With Messenger, you can send and receive messages with any of your
>   friends around the world or anyone in your mobile contacts list.
>   Messenger is available on iPhone, Android, and Blackberry.
>
> Messenger lets you:
>
> - Send messages instantly to other friends who have Messenger
> - Chat
>     with friends who are on Facebook
> - Get free push notifications for
>     incoming messages

Comment: Thanks! I installed it, its pretty good, the only problem I find is that I can't see who's online or offline on it.